# How to subscribe to package coming from array of Hiera?

Tags: puppet

I've got the following in my hiera definitions:

```
# common.json
{
  "classes": [
    "sysbase",
  ],
  "sysbase::packages": [
    "less", "build-essential", "bash"
  ]
}

# dev.local.json
{
  "sysbase::packages": [
    "xmltv"
  ]
}
```

And the following class:

```
# modules/sysbase/manifests/init.pp
class sysbase($packages){
  package{ $packages :
    ensure => latest,
  }

  exec{'select-pager':
    command     => '/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --set pager /bin/less',
    user        => 'root',
    refreshonly => true,
    subscribe   => Package['less'],
  }
}
```

When I run the agent on this node:

```
$ facter hostname fqdn domain
domain => dev.local
fqdn => francois.dev.local
hostname => francois
```

I receive this error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server:
  Error 400 on SERVER:
    Invalid relationship:
      Exec[select-pager] { subscribe => Package[less] },
      because Package[less] doesn't seem to be in the catalog
```

(reformatted for readability)

To me, it's obvious the less package is included. When I ask Hiera, it even tells me so:

```
# hiera --array sysbase::packages ::hostname=francois ::domain=dev.local ::fqdn=francois.dev.local
[...
 "less",
 "build-essential",
 "bash"]
```

The installed Puppet packages on the master are:

```
# dpkg -l | grep -i puppet
ii  facter                           2.3.0-1puppetlabs1                  Ruby module for collecting simple facts about a host operating system
ii  hiera                            1.3.4-1puppetlabs1                  A simple pluggable Hierarchical Database.
ii  puppet                           3.7.3-1puppetlabs1                  Centralized configuration management - agent startup and compatibility scripts
ii  puppet-common                    3.7.3-1puppetlabs1                  Centralized configuration management
ii  puppetdb                         2.2.2-1puppetlabs1                  PuppetDB Centralized Storage.
ii  puppetdb-terminus                2.2.2-1puppetlabs1                  Connect Puppet to PuppetDB by setting up a terminus for PuppetDB.
ii  puppetlabs-release               1.0-11                              "Package to install Puppet Labs gpg key and apt repo"
ii  puppetmaster-common              3.7.3-1puppetlabs1                  Puppet master common scripts
ii  puppetmaster-passenger           3.7.3-1puppetlabs1                  Centralised configuration management - master setup to run under mod passenger
ii  ruby-rgen                        0.6.5-1puppetlabs1                  A framework supporting Model Driven Software Development (MDSD)

# puppet --version
3.7.3
```

The worst thing is not all my puppet agents report the same error!

Why is the less package not recognized? Is it because it's in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you want Hiera to merge arrays from the hierarchy (`hiera --array`), you cannot rely on Puppet's automagic parameter binding. You will have to explicitly call the `hiera_array` function instead.

```
class sysbase($packages = hiera_array('sysbase::packages'))
{
    ...
}
```

As described in the former answer, I think your mileage would be better with a design like the following:

```
class sysbase(
    $with_xmltv,
    $with_builddev,
    ...
) {
    package { [ 'less', ... ]: }
    if $with_builddec { package { ... } }
}
```

This makes it much easier to control the set of packages across your hierarchy. On the other hand, it will be very hard to set up a node *without* `build-essential` with a `hiera_array` based approach, for example.

Comment: See the [Limitations](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#limitations) section of the [Using Hiera With Puppet](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html) documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, you can make the compiler fail before making this particular check:

```
fail("Packages: $packages")
```

It should become obvious wether Puppet sees the `less` entry.

The approach of handing in package titles via Hiera is not particularly elegant, anyway, because the user can make the class manage **any** package they want, which is poor semantics.

If you really *do* want to enumerate your packages in Hiera, you can do it under a generic key and generate resources in `site.pp` or anywhere else.

To build the relationship in a safe fashion, you can use a query:

```
if 'less' in $packages {
    Package['less'] ~> Exec['select-pager']
}
```

Comment: In my case, this is a base class, which all nodes will apply. I apply basic things, as you saw above. I want curl and wget, less, bash and zsh, and a ton of other things which I'd like to keep up-to-date. What would you recommend I do instead? A class per package? That seems excessive.

Comment: Ah, well if this class is dedicated to just these resources, then yes, I guess you *are* doing what I urged above. Still, it would make for a better interface if the set of packages was coded into the manifest, and some meaningful parameters that allow each node to (un-)select a specific subset of classes to manage.

Comment: I've added a bit more information, such as the `dev.local` domain definition. I want to union the packages, not replace them, at the less generic level.

Comment: Oh that's important. That's the actual error. I'll scribble up another answer.